# many-to-many relationships between tables

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I have a database library. It has 2 tables: Reader and Book. The tables are related to each other by belongToMany. I need to implement a method that gives a book to the user. As I understand it, this data is stored in a link table, but for some reason I don’t have it? How to give a book to a reader?
Data already exists in Reader and Book tables

My models:

```
const Book = sequelize.define('Book', {
    id: {type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true},
    title: {type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false},
    author: {type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false},
    vendorCode: {type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false},
    year: {type: DataTypes.DATEONLY, allowNull: false},
    numberOfCopies: {type: DataTypes.INTEGER}
});

const Reader = sequelize.define('Reader', {
    id: {type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true},
    fullName: {type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false},
    birth: {type: DataTypes.DATEONLY, allowNull: false}
});

const ReaderBook = sequelize.define('ReaderBook', {
});

Reader.belongsToMany(Book, {through: 'ReaderBook'});
Book.belongsToMany(Reader, {through: 'ReaderBook'});

module.exports = {Book, Reader, ReaderBook};
```

My method:

```
async issueBook(req, res) {
    try {
        const {idBook, idReader} = req.body;
        const book = await Book.findByPk(idBook);
        const reader = await Reader.findByPk(idReader);
        if (!reader || !book) {
            return res.status(400).json({message: 'Reader does not exist'});
        }
        await reader.addBook(book, {through: ReaderBook}); //addBook method doesn't exist why?
        console.log(readerBook);
        return res.json("Test");
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message);
        return res.status(400).json({message: 'Error issuing a book to a reader'});
    }
};
```

Comment: First of all, try to pass `ReaderBook` into `belongsToMany` relation on creation. Replace it's string name with actual object you've created.

Comment: Thanks, i did it. But now how to give a specific book to a specific user and have it appear in the ReaderBooks table

Comment: Updated my answer with specific user and book

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, try to pass ReaderBook into belongsToMany relation on creation. Replace it's string name with actual object you've created.

```js
Reader.belongsToMany(Book, {through: ReaderBook });  
//                no qoutes here   ^          ^
Book.belongsToMany(Reader, {through: ReaderBook });
```

To be more clear you can simplify your code.
As you mentioned you have a Reader entity:

```js
const Reader = sequelize.define('Reader', { ... });
```

And Book entity:

```js
const Book = sequelize.define('Book', { ... });
```

You could ommit manual creation of junction table by just passing name of the table as string value.

```js
Reader.belongsToMany(Book, { through: 'ReaderBook' });  
Book.belongsToMany(Reader, { through: 'ReaderBook' });
```

To apply the models to database now we have to call sync on `sequelize`:

```js
await sequelize.sync({ alter: true });
```

As you see there's no necessity to define 3d table at all.
Now 'giving' book to a reader would be even easier.

```js
const book = await Book.create();
const reader = await Reader.create();  

//or find them by primary keys or whatever else  
const book = await Book.findByPk(keyId);  
const reader = await Reader.findByPk(readerId);

//here's simple adding book to the reader
await reader.addBook(book);
```

That's all, you don't even need to pass any 'through' parameters.

Comment: @RumeDiablo have you missed something when did it by yourself?

Comment: Yes, I'm a little confused, but you helped me. I have a small question, if i want to return a book, what method should i apply, addBooks gets the book, and how to remove the link?

Comment: @RumeDiablo if you will to remove the book, you could use `removeBook(book)`